# Image-processing, edge enhancement

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

**Hello I used k mean method to detect edges and that’s my results as shown in the pic but I want to get more accurate results so I need to enhance my edge detection more what methods would you suggest[**this is the results I have and I want to enhance it as points M,N and P**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nZWe.jpg) **??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please take this [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66230283/edit) this post to include your own effort into solving the problem, AKA the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your entire method is/was. Not sure what you mean when you say you're implementing k-means on your image. If you mean k-means clustering, then I have no idea why you'd use that for edge detection.

Maybe add some code to your question next time, it really makes giving you an answer easier and more worthwhile since maybe the person answering could learn from your efforts as well. **Normally, underwhelming questions lead to underwhelming answers.**

**That said**, I have a soft spot for image processing in Matlab (my MS thesis heavily relied on it) so I'll give you a "bird's eye" overview of what I'd suggest you try.

1. First, consider checking the documentation for Matlab's image processing toolbox. There are tons of examples of how to implement the various edge detection algorithms and filters that are already built-in. Your answer might likely be copy/paste from those honestly.
2. Edges of the image are slightly pixelated. If you are using some kind of structuring element to detect the edges, minimize the size of it in order to improve the accuracy of the detection (most Matlab image processing functions have arguments to do this). If that doesn't help, try different structuring element patterns.
3. Simply binarizing the image before processing it could improve your results. If not directly, then via combining the results of various filters on the binarized image.
4. As for extracting coordinates from images in Matlab. Again, Matlab has built-in functions for finding coordinates on a plot that are well documented. You could find the coordinates of the vertices during the edge detection step, or afterward by analyzing the entirety of your detected lines.
5. If all you want is the points. Why not use image analysis software such as [ImageJ](https://imagej.net/Welcome) or [Fiji](https://imagej.net/Fiji)? It is used in A LOT of academic studies in microbiology, microscopy, and image analysis.

Well, there's my all-text answer for your all-text question. Next time **include your relevant code and more detail on your solution**.

Best of luck!